# Test for file.readAsBytes from image_picker package

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

How do I cover the following line in tests:
I have a method that has the following line:

```
file.readAsBytes();
```

When the test reaches this line, execution is stopped.
No error or exception.

Here, the file is of type `PickedFile` from https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Comment: That's a future, are you awating it?

Comment: Yes. It's future. I am awaiting it.

Comment: Can you post the code from your tests?

Comment: Do you use mocked `ImagePicker` instance with overrided `getImage` method?

Comment: @Andrej
 
await tester.tap(find.byKey(logoEditActionsPickListTile));
await tester.pumpAndSettle();

so the file.readAsBytes is called inside onTap of logoEditActionsPickListTile.

Comment: @Mol0ko No because getImage has native implementation so I mocked it using channel.setMockMethodCallHandler. And if I replace file.readAsBytes() with a fixed value something like Uint8List(10) then everything works.